# does molybdenum work with flash/flex?

Tags: flash, molybdenum

no, it's not a chemistry question :-|

came across this firefox add-on, molybdenum, a capture replay testing tool (I guess it's a play on selenium), and would like to know if anyone has had any luck using it in flash/flex apps?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had some time to test my own question and the answer is No, molybdenum does not recognize these objects.  Does seem like a decent tool though as long as you're not testing flex.